# Simple batch file with delay between programs

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

So far I got this:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files\pia_manager
start pia_manager.exe
@echo off
PING 127.0.0.1 -n 16 >nul         <For the 15 second delay.
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Vuze
start Azureus.exe
```

It "works" but not really how I want, here's my current issues:

Shows a blank Cmd window during the pinging part, I'd prefer not to see anything. (I assume this is because of the ping command, not sure how else to add a delay though)

"Breaks" when converted to an .exe using "Bat to Exe Converter" so I can't add it to my start menu or give it an icon. (I tried making a shortcut it let me give it an icon but I cant pin to my start window.)

Sorry if this is too noob of a question for this site, wasn't sure where else to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need a batch file for this, a shortcut should be fine.

---

Right click on an empty section of your Desktop, choose `New` > `Shortcut`

- In the Create Shortcut window:

  - Type the location of the item: `%ComSpec% /Q /D /C Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\pia_manager\pia_manager.exe" 2>Nul && (Timeout 15 /NoBreak>Nul&Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Vuze\Azureus.exe" 2>Nul)`
  - Click `Next`
  - Type a name for this shortcut: `YourChosenName`
  - Click `Finish`

Right click on the new shortcut on your Desktop, choose `Properties`

- In the Run: dropdown choose `Minimized`
- Click on `Change Icon...`

  - In the Change Icon window:
  - Click `Browse...`, select your chosen icon
  - Click `OK`
- Click `Apply`
- Click `OK`

Right click the new Desktop shortcut, choose `Pin to Start`

You can now delete the shortcut on your Desktop, *which is no longer required*.

Comment: So many programs I use together so this will help in future endeavours as well, :D